# 5W LEDs on a 4W rated ceiling lamp

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

I recently purchased a ceiling lamp with 4 LED bulb slots. The specs mention that 4W bulbs should be used. Is it okay to use a 5W bulb in place of the 4W? The lamp runs on mains, and the bulbs are 220V bulbs. The higher power should not affect the circuitry in any way, but would the 1W additional heat (times 4) be over the limit for the fixture?

Comment: there should be an LED driver module in the light fixture .... if there is one, please post a picture of the label on the driver

Comment: Have you actually witnessed with  your own eyes that the lamp has sockets and removable "bulbs"?  Or are you just assuming that?

Comment: @jsotola: I will check that and get back to you. Harper: yes, I have seen/mounted the bulbs.

Comment: The LED’s are normally controlled by a driver and the wrong lamps can cause the driver to fail the lights to be dim or strobe and other issues.

Comment: There seem to be no ICs on the lamp fixture. Couldn't upload a photo here, but here is how it looks on the inside (https://mega.nz/file/GeACVLgB#1FAF7J8UXlgpBj0_v8Mkf7BEvvKG23GE-lqHyxoD2Dg.

Comment: @jsotola, and others: did you get a chance to look at the picture